# How can I make Mathematica calculate a volume given a set of inequalities on the the three dimensions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

How can I make Mathematica calculate a volume given a set of inequalities over three dimensional space?

I know how to plot the 3D region of the volume that I need to calculate, like this:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && y >= Abs[x]/Sqrt[3] && y <= 1/2, 
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

It yields as output the figure:

[image: Output 1]

But how can I calculate its volume? Do I have to set up an integral? Is that the only way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in one line of that Mathematica code

```
 Volume[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1&&y>= RealAbs[x]/Sqrt[3] && y<= 1/2, {x, y, z}]]
```

> $\frac{17 \pi }{72}$

Comment: Love it. There is no reference of it in the documentation of Volume[] though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zurg: See [that reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Volume.html) for `Volume` in 3D.

Comment: BTW, In arbitrary dimension, you can use `RegionMeasure` to achieve the same end result